# How to bind WPF TextBlock to right top corner?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

Please help me to edit XAML so the `TextBlock` which shows minutes **goes to the right top corner.**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <TextBlock Name="UserNameTextBlock"  Margin="0,0,8,0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock   FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Foreground="LightGray" >@</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock  FontSize="13"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="ScreenNameTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Path=ScreenName}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock  FontSize="13"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="MinAgo"  Text="{Binding Path=MinAgo}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>    
     </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

So it should be like

[image]

Comment: You could try HorizontalAllignment = right but I doubt it will work for a stack panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a [DockPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html).  For the child nodes, just add DockPanel.Dock attributes to indicate where you want the element to go.  The last child element will automatically fill the remaining area.

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="13"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="MinAgo"  Text="{Binding Path=MinAgo}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBlock Name="UserNameTextBlock"  Margin="0,0,8,0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Foreground="LightGray" >@</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="ScreenNameTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Path=ScreenName}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Personally I rarely use DockPanels, hence my answer below involving a grid. Granted, it would do the job, but it's less intuitive to figure out what's going on just from looking at the XAML.

Answer (score 4):

If I were doing this I would use a grid rather than a horizontal stack panel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Name="UserNameTextBlock"  Margin="0,0,8,0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Foreground="LightGray" >@</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="13"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="ScreenNameTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Path=ScreenName}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"  FontSize="13"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,0,0,1" Name="MinAgo"  Text="{Binding Path=MinAgo}" Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Note the * in the column 3 which means that column will use all available space after column 2, except for what is needed by column 4.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `StackPanel` but a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) with columns?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: Add one `*`-sized column before the one with the time, make everything else `Auto`.